# Pocket billiards with balls in general position

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, classical-mechanics, billiards

There were at least two earlier MO questions about ideal pocket billiards.
(Ideal: frictionless, perfectly elastic collisions.)

- [Perfectly centered break of a perfectly aligned pool ball rack](https://mathoverflow.net/q/156263/6094).
- [Does there exist a shot in ideal pocket billiards?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/44296/6094).

  - Answered *Not always* by George Lowther with a clever example:
  - [image: George_detail]

My question is a variation on whether there is always a shot.
George Lowther's example involved touching or nearly touching balls,
and collinear balls, and forces the cue ball into a pocket--a "scratch."
Here I ask for more generic situations:

> ***Q***.
> With the initial ball centers in general position (no three collinear),
> is there an $\epsilon > 0$ such that, if initially every pair of balls is separated by
> at least $\epsilon$, there always exists a shot that sinks at least one
> ball and avoids a scratch?

My guess is *Yes*, perhaps with $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ (and unit-radius balls).
And maybe there is always a shot that sinks all $15$ balls?

$\mathfrak{Merry}$ $\mathfrak{Christmas!}$

[image: Grinch_detail]

<sup>[Chuck Jones Gallery](https://www.chuckjonescatalog.com/grinch-oneofones/grinch-with-cue-stick).</sup>